# Appium: Click within webview context of iOS results to double click

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm having a problem with a click action within a webview context on iOS.  The click works but the single click action is resulting in double click.  The way i can tell is that the resulting action execute 2 times, for example: click on a button to show a popup alert, when the click execute the alert shows 2 times.

**System:**
- Mac/OSX, Appium v1.4.10, iPhone 6 8.1 sim

**Appium log snapshot**: taken from where it did the click action within web view context

```
nfo: --> POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//i[contains(@class,'icon-play')]/parent::a"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 100ms for condition
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5006"},"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element 200 11.588 ms - 90 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5006"},"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element/5006/displayed {}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'is_displayed' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element/5006/displayed 200 13.478 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element/5006/click {"id":"5006"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Executing 'click' atom in default context
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Got a blank data response from debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/element/5006/click 200 62.000 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Got a blank data response from debugger
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"WEBVIEW_17","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context 200 0.654 ms - 84 {"status":0,"value":"WEBVIEW_17","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context {"name":"NATIVE_APP"}
info: [debug] Attempting to set context to 'NATIVE_APP'
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context 200 1.138 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"NATIVE_APP","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/context 200 0.640 ms - 84 {"status":0,"value":"NATIVE_APP","sessionId":"6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/6e51e9be-4b04-4557-ada0-e2c4a57dcf7c/elements {"using":"name","value":"Video Ad Player"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 100ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElementsByName('Video Ad Player')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementsByName('Video Ad Player')
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-09-05 01:14:07 +0000 Debug: Got new command 220 from instruments: au.getElementsByName('Video Ad Player')
info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
i
```

Comment: can you please share your code how you are running your tests.

Comment: Here's the basic code : 

`driver.context("WEBVIEW"); 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='test_button']")); 
element.click();`

Comment: i don't see anything wrong. May be just try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='test_button']")).click();